# How to randomly select a string

Tags: c#, random

When I click a button a string should appear as output ex. `good morning` or `good afternoon`. How can I use C# to randomly select the string to display?

Comment: Not a serverfault question, use stackoverflow instead.

Comment: Can you please explain a little more as to what you want?  What do you mean by random?  Do you want it to say Good morning in the morning and good afternoon in the afternoon?

Comment: As array is mentioned nowhere in the question I've rolled back your changes spoon16 - way too big an assumption, changing to question to fit your answer is cheating :p

Comment: That wasn't my intention. I was just trying to make it more understandable/readable.  I have reapplied without mention of an array.

Answer (score 12):

It has been a couple of years (3-4) since I have been programming with C# but isn't this simple & elegant enough:

```
string randomPick(string[] strings)
{
    return strings[random.Next(strings.Length)];
}
```

You should also check if the input array is not `null`.

Answer (score 6):

You can define an extension method to pick a random element of any `IEnumerable` (including string arrays):

```
public static T RandomElement<T>(this IEnumerable<T> coll)
{
    var rnd = new Random();
    return coll.ElementAt(rnd.Next(coll.Count()));
}
```

Usage:

```
string[] messages = new[] { "good morning", "good afternoon" };
string message = messages.RandomElement();
```

The nice thing here is that `ElementAt` and `Count` have optimized versions for arrays and List objects, while the algorithm is generalized for use with all finite collection types.

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
Random random = new Random();
string[] weekDays = new string[] { "Sat", "Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri" };
Response.Write(weekDays[random.Next(6)]);
```

All you need is a string array and a random number to pull a value from the array.